# Modaldialog doesn't react to enter/esc

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog

I have a modaldialog with an <kbd>OK</kbd> and a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button. For the <kbd>OK</kbd> I set the `Default` property to True, and for the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button the `Cancel` property. ModalResult is set to `mrOK` and `mrCancel`, resp.

However neither pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> nor the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on my keyboard close the dialog. What did I miss here?

**edit**
I posted a [small test application](http://stevenvh.net/files/modaldlg.zip) using the suspect dialog on my site. IDE is RAD Studio XE3.

[image]

Comment: Did you set the ModalResult properties to mrOk/mrCancel?

Comment: @lurd - Yes, I did (otherwise the buttons wouldn't work either). I'll add the info to my question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you invoke the modal dialog with the `ShowModal` method? Just to make sure. Otherwise I suggest you make a small compilable example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @lurd - Yes, I invoke `ShowModal`. I posted a [test application on my site](http://stevenvh.net/files/modaldlg.zip).

Comment: This appears to be something to do with TSpinEdit; If you add a TEdit to the form then Enter and Esc work correctly when the TEdit is focused, but not when the TSpinEdit is focused.

Comment: @davea, a TStringGrid behaves the same as TSpinEdit when the TStringGrid editor is active. With the editor inactive, the esc closes the dialog, while enter invokes the editor (with goEditing option set).

Answer (score 5):

From your posted example you can see that the `TSpinEdit` control is focused and captures the keys.

To close the modal form in all cases, set form `KeyPreview` to true and insert this into the `OnKeyPress` event:

```
procedure TSelectDlg.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = Char(vk_escape)) then  // #27
    CancelBtn.Click
  else
  if (Key = Char(vk_return)) then  // #13
    OkBtn.Click;    
end;
```

Comment: While I agree that this solves the issue (thanks for that) it leaves a new question: what's the use of the `Cancel` and `Default` properties if we have to write code ourselves to emulate keypresses? Also, this code is also required if I don't have the `setfocus` line.

Comment: If you tab to focus the OK button, you can exit with return key without this additional code. This is the default windows behavior. The cancel and default properties get handled when there are no other focused control capturing the keys.

Comment: Got it. Looks like I expected too much from the `Cancel` and `Default` properties :-). (It's been a while since I used Delphi for the last time)

Comment: It's not a delphi issue, this is platform standard behaviour

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is a Delphi isue. Go and check the TSpinEdit implementation and you will se why. The methods that you wanna check are TSpinEdit.KeyPress and TSpinEdit.IsValidChar.

Comment: @Silver I don't think it has anything to do with those methods. But I'm wrong about platform standard. Single line edit doesn't want to process enter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Set a few breakpoints in those methods and do some testing. You will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @silver it's as Allen says

Answer (score 5):

For the record, this should work. However, it seems that TSpinEdit has a bug. Since TSpinEdit is a sample (Vcl.Samples.Spin.pas, note the "Samples"), you can fix this yourself.

To TSpinEdit, add the following method declaration just following WMCut:

```
   procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
```

Complete the class (Shift+Ctrl+C) and add the following code to WMGetDlgCode:

```
procedure TSpinEdit.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := Message.Result and not DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
end;
```

That will tell VCL that the edit control doesn't want to process the Enter and Escape keys (VK_ENTER, VK_ESCAPE). Since it doesn't process the keys, they'll be forwarded to the buttons, which will then be invoked base on their settings (Default & Cancel).

Feel free to report this at [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com)

Comment: Maybe it's time to consider replacing that "sample" by real [`up-down control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759880(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Like the TUpDown component? Been there for a while, like since Delphi 2 or 3.

Comment: Reported as [QC125891 TSpinEdit captures vk_return and vk_escape keys](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125891).

Comment: @LURD Can you edit the QC please. This problem has been presistand since Delphi 7 if not even older Delphi versions. Delphi 7 has compiler version of 15 but you entered 20 which equals for Delphi 2009.

Comment: @SilverWarior, 20 is Delphi-XE6. I'm not sure, but I think one is supposed to add the latest version that exhibits the bug. Anyway I added a note about this being present since at least D7.

Comment: 27 is XE6. 15 is Delphi 7. @SilverWarior is correct, 20 is D2009.

Comment: When reporting a QC, and tick the latest version, you get version 20. I guess it refers to the build number of the IDE.

Comment: Most likely is that someone hasn't update the QC association for "latest version". QC is set to be retired in the near future and be replaced with Jira, which is what we're using internally at this point.