# How to patch TSpinEdit to use Vista/Win7 visual style?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Win7 must give ok style for TSpinEdit, but I see outdated style:

[image]

So arrows are not themed, and buttons are old.
I use Delphi7. How to patch VCL to fix style?
OK is:

[image]

Comment: Best you can do is to provide your own Glyphs: `TSpinEdit.Button.DownGlyph/UpGlyph`

Comment: *"buttons are old"* - That's not correct. Actually VCL use themes to draw buttons as long as you have 'xpman'. Buttons are derived from TSpeedButton. Increase the edit height (set autosize to false), and you'll see. *"arrows are not themed"* - See above comment.

Comment: "buttons are old" means different size of buttons. Shot#2 shows ok sizes. Any way to fast fix sizes?

Comment: For same edit height, fix up/down sizes?

Comment: I think easiest would be to put a copy of 'spin.pas' in your project folder, then modify the code in TSpinButton.AdjustSize.

Comment: You've got the code. Why not use it as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Delphi 7 already had it but you can use `TEdit` in combination with `TUpDown` and then set the `Association` property of the `TUpDown` to your `TEdit`.

Comment: I think `TUpDown` was introduced in Delphi-5, or perhaps even sooner, since it is a wrapper for a windows control.

Comment: Then try kobik's suggestion, setting your own glyphs.

Comment: @RProgram You can always define your own `TSpinEdit`, keeping the same interface, but internally composed as described above.

Comment: @LURD, yup, [`a bit sooner`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584190/modaldialog-doesnt-react-to-enter-esc/24591100#comment38098490_24591100) :-)

Answer (score 2):

`TSpinEdit` is a custom VCL control. There is no Windows control with that functionality.  Even in the latest version of Delphi it looks exactly the same as in Delphi 7. And it's really rather ugly isn't it?

The control, in modern Delphi, is implemented in a unit named `Vcl.Samples.Spin`. Looking at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Samples) for the `Vcl.Samples` namespace we have:

> Contains the units for several sample VCL components delivered with RAD Studio - a calendar, an outline, a gauge, and a spinbutton.

The unit will be named differently in Delphi 7, but the principle is the same. These are sample controls, supplied with source code.

So, what you may do is take a copy of the `TSpinEdit` code, and modify the painting. Change the button drawing to be how you wish it to be.